# Maven inject plugin settings.xml

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-plugin

I'm currently setting up a CI/CD chain for multiple projects. I'd like to inject a maven plugin with every build of our Jenkins server (this one: https://github.com/cedricwalter/git-branch-renamer-maven-plugin). Is there a way to inject the plugin into a build without adding it to every pom.xml in every project?

Comment: You can add the plugin in a parent pom.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with mavenSettings.xml using the `profile` section: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Then set that mavenSettings.xml to the Maven instalation used by Jenkins.

```
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>AllwaysOn</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        ...
      </activation>

      <!-- add plugin config here -->
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  ...
```

Then you can add your specific plugin configuration there.

Comment: It would be more helpful to show an example of what that configuration would look like in your code snippet itself, instead of a comment stub.

Comment: There is NO mavenSettings.xml file in use available for maven.